# Undo the effects of changing meta_key from Varchar to int

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, meta-key

I was trying to edit the email form field so that it accepts int values like of a phone number. I knew very less about how database values work and this is what i did:
1. Figured out that email field was "hrb_email"
2. Found that in wp_metauser hrb_email is a meta_key
3. Went to structure> and changed the meta_key from varchar to int.

Result:
I cant find hrb_email in wp_metauser any more.
Wordpress dashboard shows no users. Although wp_users has my user details.
Also, on my website, I can see user if I manually put the URL for those users but I cant find them on the list on my website.

Please advice. 
Note: changing the meta_key value back to varchar does not help.

This is what meta_key looks like[image: Changed back to varchar][image: I cant find hrb)email under meta_key anymore]

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: Thanks @MarcDelisle . The following day i realized what I had done. I created a new user and according to the meta keys of the new user, updated the old ones. I got the hang of it after updating 30 users and 600 fields. Took me 2 days and all users are back live. Just had to update their password from backend and informed the users. Taught me a lesson, never to mess with this again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the meta_key fields manually for each user. To achieve this, I created a couple of new users and understood what values belonged to the key fields. From that, i started updating the meta_key field manually. It worked for all the users, except that i had to update password on Wordpress>dashboard>users>edit.